# follow vs following

Tags: grammar

I have two simple questions:

In the sentence:

> "There is no greater thing to do than follow your passions in a way that serves the world and you."

Why should we say "follow" and not "following"?
As it says "passions" why does "serve" have an "s"?

Answer (score 2):

> Why should we say "follow" and not "following"?

Because "continuous" verbs are effectively adjectives, and a verb is needed in that position. It's an imperative phrase there, "follow your passions"

> As it says "passions" why does "serve" have an "s"?

Because the "way" (the method or manner in which you go about your passions) is a singular, and that's what's doing the serving.

Comment: @Itmauve It seems to me that **follow** in OP's example is a **bare infinitive** rather than an imperative. What's more I see no problem with using the gerund construction **..than following your passions....** as an alternative. What I don't follow is your reasoning.